# Short-circuit evaluation via the AND operator in PHP

Tags: php, and-operator

I'm trying to improve my coding ninja h4x skills, and I'm currently looking at different frameworks, and I have found sample code that's pretty hard to google.

I am looking at the [FUEL framework](https://github.com/ccschmitz/short-sale-management) used in a project.

The sample I don't understand is

```
$data and $this->template->set_global($data);
```

What is the **and** keyword doing in this line of code? It is used many places in the framework and it's the first that I have found that uses it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a type of "[short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_circuit_evaluation)". The `and/&&` implies that both sides of the comparison must evaluate to `TRUE`.

The item on the left of the `and/&&` is evaluated to `TRUE/FALSE` and if `TRUE`, the item on the right is executed and evaluated. If the left item is `FALSE`, execution halts and the right side isn't evaluated.

```
$data = FALSE;
// $this->template->set_global($data) doesn't get evaluated!
$data and $this->template->set_global($data);

$data = TRUE;
// $this->template->set_global($data) gets evaluated
$data and $this->template->set_global($data);
```

Note these don't have to be actual boolean `TRUE/FALSE`, but can also be truthy/falsy values according to PHP's evaluation rules. See the [PHP boolean docs](http://php.net/manual/language.types.boolean.php) for more info on evaluation rules.

Answer (score 4):

When you use logical operators, operands (the value on the left and the value on the right) are evaluated as boolean, so basically that code will do this, in a shorter way:

```
$o1 = (Bool)$data; // cast to bool
if($o1)
    $o2 = (Bool)$this->template->set_global($data); // cast to bool
```

Edit:

Some additional information:

```
$a = 33;
isset($a) && print($a) || print("not set");
echo "<br>";
isset($a) AND print($a) OR print("not set");
echo "<br>";
```

Try to comment/decomment `$a = 33;`. This is the difference between `&&` and `AND`, and between `||` and `OR` (`print` returns true that is casted to "1" when converted to string).

Answer (score 2):

It is a valid statement and works like this:

> If $data is valid (is not '', 0 or NULL) then run $this->template->set_global($data)

It's a quick way of saying:

```
if ($data)
{
    $this->template->set_global($data);
}
```

Btw you can also use `&&` instead of `and`

Comment: Wrong, if you use `||`, it will evaluate the right side only if the left side is not truthy.

Answer (score 0):

PHP supports both `&&` and `and` for the logical AND operation, and they generally work identically, except `and` has a slightly lower operator precedence than `&&`: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: you misunderstood the question

Comment: Even though it doesn't directly address the question, +1 for mentioning precedence differences.

Answer (score -2):

It's a [boolean operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operator) which means it takes two operands and returns a boolean value-- `true` or `false`. If both operands evaluate to `true` (anything but and empty string, zero or null in PHP) it will return `true`, otherwise the result will be `false`.

Here's PHP's official docs on the `and` operator: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

```
<?php
$a = true and false; # FALSE
$b = true and 5; # TRUE
$c = '' and 0; # FALSE
$d = null and true; # FALSE
?>
```

Comment: you misunderstood the question