# What does ||  mean?

Tags: javascript, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this construct mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-this-construct-mean)

I'm encountering this syntax for the first time and am not sure what it's doing:

```
self.name = _searchString(settings.dataBrowser) || "An unknown browser";
```

What does the or (double pipes) condition do? When would self.name be set to the second value?

Comment: I believe that happens when the first is null? I could be wrong though.

Comment: Don't see anything jQuery related here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the logical `or` operator.

It evaluates to its first "truthy" operand.

In particular, it will evaluate to the second operand if the first operand is "falsy" — `null`, `false`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, or `NaN`.

Comment: Basically a coalesce operator!  Gotta love it..

Answer (score 0):

Crockford calls / called it a [default operator](http://javascript.crockford.com/style2.html)

Answer (score 0):

this is directly related to a question i have asked, you can read about it here
[Short-circuit evaluation via the AND operator in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665101/the-and-operator-in-php)

so basically, it sets self.name to the value returned from the function, but if the function returns false, it sets itself to "An unknown browser";