# What does "||" mean?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm newbie and trying to study javascript myself.

There is an example:

```
 var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop
```

I just wonder what does the symbol " ||" do? Thank you! Appreciate your help.

Comment: That's JavaScript's [logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), which returns the value of the first operand if it is truthy, otherwise returns the value of the second operand.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851404/what-does-options-options-mean-in-javascript , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718259/what-does-mean (and *many* more, I just searched on SO for `[javascript] "||"`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that you are trying to get the `document.documentElement.scrollTop` function but if it returns `undefined` (because the function is not supported in the given browser) it will use the `document.body.scrollTop` function instead.

Comment: If `document.documentElement.scrollTop` _is_ defined but happens to have the value `0` then the statement will take the value of `document.body.scrollTop`.

Answer (score 0):

If `document.documentElement.scrollTop` is `undefined` or `null`,`scrollTop=document.body.scrollTop`

Answer (score 0):

Here `||` Logical OR operator.

```
Logical OR operator returns the first value of first operand if that is truthy
otherwise it returns the second operand.
```

The above statement is same as

```
if(document.documentElement.scrollTop){
   var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop
}
else{
   var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop
}
```

Comment: _"has a value except null/undefined"_ - or zero or false or empty string or NaN.

Comment: @nnnnnn updated my answer. I got that `0`,`''` & `NaN` are also falsy.